# Formula to Count Numbers in a Range IF the Cell Above it has a Specific Text

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to count the number of days in a cell if the cell above it has a specific NAME.
Basically trying to calculate the number of days someoone works.See this image. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxH20.png).

I'd love some help with a formula.

I've trying countif and offset, but I can't seem to make it work.
This is what i tried: =COUNTIF(Offset(D6:J6,-1,0,0)="Name 1")

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have different feature sets and will most likely require a different answer each. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with [excel]"_ and the [excel] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]."_ Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample setup with a formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(D7:L7,D6:L6=C11)))
```

ALTERNATE FORMULA:

```
=SUMIF(D6:L6,C11,D7:L7)
```

- 

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Week:`=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(D7:L7,D6:L6=C11,REGEXMATCH(D2:L2,"Week\b"))))`

Weekend: `=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(D7:L7,D6:L6=C11,REGEXMATCH(D2:L2,"Weekend"))))`

-

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need `IFERROR` at least for Excel, maybe for Google Spreadsheet. Unless you want to prevent the value was not found and for that you can use the third input argument of `FILTER`.

Comment: Hi! This is so helpful! It worked, but I just realized that I also need another condition to further break up the on call days between weeks and weekends. How do I add another filter that sums the numbers if there is cell in the column contains the word 'week' or 'weekend'? It would be a specific row.

Comment: Update the answer to take week(end) into account.